# how to replace symbol " ," with " ', ' " in sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a SQL query such that it has to replace a `,` to a `','` to the string that am passing. The string am passing is like `jack,john,tony` but the output am getting is empty table only with column header.

can you provide a answer for this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetBillingSystem]
(
@BillingCode VARCHAR(300)
)
AS
BEGIN 
declare @ListOfPlanID varchar(30)
declare  @trimmed varchar(30)
declare  @replaced varchar(30)
set @ListOfPlanID =@BillingCode


If  IsNull(@ListOfPlanID,'')='' return 
If LEN(@ListOfPlanID)=0 return 
SET @trimmed=LTRIM(RTRIM(@ListOfPlanID))
set @replaced=''''+REPLACE(@trimmed,',',''',''')+''''   
select * from BillingSystem where BillingCode IN (@replaced)
END
```

In vb.net i written a code for get datatable from above sql query this way

```
Public Function getBillingSystemAttributesInfo(ByVal ConnectionString As String, ByVal                      BillingCode As String) As DataTable
Dim conn As SqlConnection
Dim sqlcmd As SqlCommand
Dim dtBillingSystem As DataTable
Try
conn = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
conn.Open()
sqlcmd = New SqlCommand("usp_GetBillingSystem", conn)
With sqlcmd

.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure


 .Parameters.Add("@BillingSystemCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300)
 .Parameters("@BillingSystemCode").Value = BillingSystemCode

  dataadapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
  dataadapter.SelectCommand = sqlcmd
  dtBillingSystem = New DataTable("BillingSystem")
  dataadapter.Fill(dtBillingSystem)
   End With
   Catch ex As Exception
    Throw ex
    Finally
    conn.Close()
    sqlcmd = Nothing
    End Try
    Return dtBillingSystem
End Function
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what you do to the string contained in `@replaced`. So long as you are passing a *single* string argument to the `IN()` operator, it will continue to be treated as a *single* string. This is not surprising. Can you name *any* programming language where the system will suddenly decide to inspect the contents of a string, see commas and quote characters, and decide to magically convert a single value into multiple values?

Comment: when we pass string to the IN it should enclose with single quoted or else it give an error so am replacing ',' to "',". the input am giving to the query in 020,N20,G19 after replacing set (@replaced=''''+REPLACE(@trimmed,',',''',''')+''''  )it become ('020','N20','G19')like this only we have to give string in IN right

Comment: No, you're still, somehow, not understanding what I've said above. The *single* string containing `'abc','def','ghi'` is not at all the same thing as three *separate* strings, passed to `IN()` as three separate arguments, separated by commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you cannot pass a variable to IN operator, You have to use the dynamic SQL here

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetBillingSystem]
(
@BillingCode VARCHAR(300)
)
AS
BEGIN 
declare @ListOfPlanID varchar(30)
declare  @trimmed varchar(30)
declare  @replaced varchar(30)
set @ListOfPlanID =@BillingCode


If  IsNull(@ListOfPlanID,'')='' return 
If LEN(@ListOfPlanID)=0 return 
SET @trimmed=LTRIM(RTRIM(@ListOfPlanID));

set @replaced=''''+REPLACE(@trimmed,',',''',''')+'''';
declare @qry nvarchar(max);
set @qry = 'select * from BillingSystem where BillingCode IN (' + @replaced + ')';
exec sp_executesql @qry
end
```

Comment: parameter which goes to the sql query is string "020,N19,A04". when i executed ur sql it giving a error of Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: @Sushma Gowda
Try replacing the line
 set @replaced=REPLACE(@trimmed,',',''',''');
with this
 set @replaced=''''+REPLACE(@trimmed,',',''',''')+'''';

Comment: i tried in that way also in my my code i wrote code same as you mentioned i hope u saw the sql code .its giving syntax error.

Comment: i copied n pasted your code in my code.and its giving error

Comment: This works fine with me

`ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetBillingSystem]
(
@BillingCode VARCHAR(300)
)
AS
BEGIN 
declare @ListOfPlanID varchar(30)
declare  @trimmed varchar(30)
declare  @replaced varchar(30)
set @ListOfPlanID =@BillingCode


If  IsNull(@ListOfPlanID,'')='' return 
If LEN(@ListOfPlanID)=0 return 
SET @trimmed=LTRIM(RTRIM(@ListOfPlanID));

set @replaced=''''+REPLACE(@trimmed,',',''',''')+'''';
declare @qry nvarchar(max);
set @qry = 'select * from BillingSystem where BillingCode IN (' + @replaced + ')';
exec sp_executesql @qry
end
Go 
EXEC [usp_GetBillingSystem] '020,N20,G19'`

Comment: try the above code
`EXEC [usp_GetBillingSystem] '020,N20,G19'` in SSMS and see what the query printed. posting that would help

Comment: yes, its working thanks a lot.......i copied n pasted above comment code its working...

Answer (score 0):

i am giving you a function that work as replacer but it is in postgresql so you modify according to your database language..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_replacer(to_rep character varying, by_rep character varying, str character varying)
 RETURNS character varying
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
res varchar2(100);

BEGIN
    for i in 1.. length(str)
    loop
    res:= res||(case when substr(str,i,1)=TO_rep then by_rep else substr(str,i,1) end); 
    end loop;

return res;
end $function$;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to replace any thing. If you are using "IN" for dynamic values you need to prepare a query by your self dynamically.

replace your code by

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetBillingSystem]
(
   @BillingCode VARCHAR(300)
)
AS

BEGIN 

  exec('select * from BillingSystem where BillingCode IN ('+@BillingCode+')')

END
```

it will surely work

Comment: when i passed '020,G19' its giving error of invalid column name '020' invalid column name 'G19'

Comment: Show me a code in which you are using "usp_GetBillingSystem" Strored Procedure

Comment: i added a code of vb.net where am using "usp_GetBillingSystem"

Comment: Prepare "BillingCode" in form of '020','G19'